# Ember.js - Accessing nested data via serializer

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

What is the best approach for accessing a single nested record in Ember?

The JSON response which we are trying to manipulate looks gets returned as the following: (the attribute being targeted is the *tradeIdentifier* property)

```
trade:
    tradeIdentifier:"83f3f561-62af-11e7-958b-028c04d7e8f9"
    tradeName:"Plumber"
userEmail:"test@gmail.com"
```

The `project-user` model looks partially like:

```
  email: attr('string'),
  trade:attr(),
  tradeId: attr(),
```

The `project-user` serializer looks partially like:

```
export default UndefinedOmitted.extend(EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  primaryKey: 'userRoleId',
  attrs: {
    'email': { key: 'userEmail' },
    'trade': { key: 'trade' },
    'tradeId': { key: 'tradeIdentifier' },
  },
});
```

The `trade` attr here is a placeholder to make sure that the data was accessible.
I would like to be able to access the `tradeIdentifier` without having to do the following in the component:

```
const trade = get(formRole, 'trade');
if (trade) {
  set(formProps, 'tradeId', trade.tradeIdentifier);
}
```

Have tested creating a `trade-id` transform (referenced via `tradeId: attr('trade-id')`), however to no avail.

```
export default Transform.extend({
  deserialize(val) {

    const trade = val;
    const tradeId = val.tradeIdentifier;

    return tradeId;
  },
  serialize(val) {
    return val;
  },
});
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The transform should be applied to your `trade`, the value for `tradeId` is empty cause you don't have any property called `tradeIdentifier` in your payload. Did you tested out to use a nested key on `attrs`? Like `attrs: { tradeId: { key: 'trade.tradeIdentifier' } }`. Never tried that myself, but it might work.

Comment: @jelhan - yep, tried `attrs: { tradeId: { key: 'trade.tradeIdentifier' } }`, doesn't seem to work (would be nice if it did). Ended up getting the transform to work; will post solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transform seems a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achieve here, however it does the job. Managed to get it working by modifying the following:

In **serializers/project-user.js**:

`'tradeId': { key: 'trade' },`

Note that this references the property in the payload to transform, not the property being targeted (which was my mistake).

In **models/project-user.js**:

`tradeId: attr('trade-id'),`

Attribute references the transform.

In **transform/trade-id.js**:

```
export default Transform.extend({
  deserialize(val) {

    let tradeId = val
    if (tradeId) {
      tradeId = val.tradeIdentifier;
    }

    return tradeId;
  },
  serialize(val) {
    return val;
  },
});
```

If there's a simpler solution outside of transforms, I would still be open to suggestions.